# How come a Fourier transform approaches zero as the oscillation frequency increases?

Tags: fourier-transform, frequency, mathematics, approximations

[image: Page 156 of Radiative Processes in Astrophysics Rybicki & Lightman]

I'm somewhat confused as to why the Fourier transform goes to zero.
The only mathematical proof I've found which might be applicable is the [Riemann-Lebesgue lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann%E2%80%93Lebesgue_lemma), but I'm not sure that applies here. Maybe a more intuitive understanding is possible?

Comment: The stationary phase approximation is related to this. The intuition is that if $\dot{v}$ is not changing significantly during one period then the integral of $\dot{v} \exp(i\omega t)$ over a period vanishes. (A more thorough analysis is needed to be sure the limit is correct of course.)

Comment: Indeed, the Riemann lemma describes this phenomenon. When integrating product of a continuous function and a sine function, the higher the frequency of oscillation of the sine function, the smaller the integral.